# calculating logistic map in real time misses many results

Tags: loops, matplotlib

Many code examples of calculating the logistic map function

[image: logistic map function]

use arrays. For example

```
%matplotlib notebook 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def logistic(r, x):
    return r * x * (1 - x)
n = 1000
r = np.linspace(2.5, 4., n)
iterations = 1000
last = 900
x = 1e-5 * np.ones(n)
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
for i in range(iterations):
    x = logistic(r, x)
    if i >= (iterations - last):
        ax1.plot(r, x, ',k', alpha=.25)
ax1.set_xlim(2.5, 4)
ax1.set_title("Bifurcation diagram")
```

This is the result:

[image]

However, I am trying to make real time plot of the function. My attempt results in many values being omitted.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
%matplotlib notebook 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def logistic(r, s):
    return r * s * (1 - s)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.ion()

fig.show()
fig.canvas.draw()

#j goes from 2.5 to 4
for j in [float(j) / 100 for j in range(250, 400, 1)]:
    x=0.2
    # for a given value of j, iterate the logistic function 1000x
    for i in range(1000):
        y=logistic(j, x)
        x=y
    #plot the iterated logistic function for a given value of j
    ax.plot(j,y,'ko',markersize=1)
    fig.canvas.draw()
```

It looks really bad.

[image]

It seems half the data is missing and the data points for larger values of r appear sparse. How can I iterate the logistic function to obtain all the values for a given r?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Basically, the logistic map 'explodes' and becomes chaotic only after it is iterated a few times. So, I have to iterate a few times 'silently' (to allow the function to converge if it will) and then to print out the next few iterated values like so.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
%matplotlib notebook 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
def logistic(r, s):
    return r * s * (1 - s)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.ion()

fig.show()
fig.canvas.draw()

#j goes from 2.5 to 4
j=2.5
#for j in [float(j) / 500 for j in range(1250, 2000, 1)]:
while j<4:
    x=0.2
    # for a given value of j, iterate the logistic function 1000x
    for i in range(30):
        y=logistic(j, x)
        x=y
    for i in range(50):
        y=logistic(j, x)
        ax.plot(j,y,'ko',markersize=.2)
        x=y
    #plot the iterated logistic function for a given value of j
    fig.canvas.draw()
    j=j+.01
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: I dont know why it slows down tho as j approaches 4.